# Android Marshmallow - How to avoid Wi-Fi drop if No Internet access

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-wifi

I'm writing an app that connects to an hotspot with no internet connection.
It seems that on some Nexus devices with Android Marshmallow, when you connect to a network with no internet requests, the system "drops" the wifi connection and all request are not sent to the hotspot connection.

After a few seconds,  a notification pops up asking if you want to stay connected to it. When the answer is "Yes", requests are sent to the hotspot successfully and you're able to get responses.

[image]

I've encountered the following thread:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131132/force-marshmallow-to-keep-a-wi-fi-without-internet-access

However, I'm looking for a programmatically way (for not rooted devices) to tackle this problem. 
I'm currently connecting to Wifi networks with the following code:

```
public void connectTo(String capabilities, String password, String ssid) {
    WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
    if (capabilities.contains("WPA2")) {
        conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";
    } else if (capabilities.contains("WPA")) {
        conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";
    } else if (capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
        conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + password + "\"";
        conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    } else {
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    }

    mWifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = mWifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    if (list == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
        if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
            mWifiManager.disconnect();
            mWifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            mWifiManager.reconnect();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```